# Visio 2010 - change title attribute when exporting to SVG

Tags: svg, visio

I want to embed a couple of SVGs into a website which contain links.
What I am struggling with is the hover text that is displayed on a link.

[image]

Instead of "**Tabelle.28**" which seems to be auto-generated I want to put something more meaningful but the only way I found is to edit the text of the title element inside the SVG. Within Visio I couldn't find this **title** element anywhere.

```
<g id="shape28-1" v:mID="28" v:groupContext="shape" transform="translate(1.5,-3.4728)">
                <title>Tabelle.28</title>
                <desc>Testing</desc>
```

Any ideas how I can change this element from within Visio?

Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visio for Office 365, and I can edit those elements from the Diagram Navigation pane (**View > Task Panes > Navigation**).

Comment: I do not have this option: in task panes I only have "Shapes", "Shape Data", "Pan & Zoom", "Size & Position". Still looking for an option to edit the title directly in visio (and not in SVG where changes are lost on next export).